# grouping similar values together

Tags: python

I have a string with multiple records with each vale in it's own dic.

```
x = [{'bsName': 'AC SLEEPER'}, {'bsType': 'ACS'}, {'ischildconcession': 'N'}, {'isseatlayot': 'N'}, {'isseatnmber': 'N'}, {'bsName': 'AC-JANRATH'}, {'bsType': 'JNR'}, {'ischildconcession': 'N'}, {'isseatlayot': 'Y'}, {'isseatnmber': 'Y'}]
```

There are only 5 columns in the database.

```
bsName , bsType , ischildconcession , isseatlayot , isseatnmber
```

So the result should be like this...

```
y = [{'bsName': 'AC SLEEPER', 'bsType': 'ACS', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'N', 'isseatnmber': 'N'}, {'bsName': 'AC-JANRATH', 'bsType': 'JNR', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'Y', 'isseatnmber': 'Y'}]
```

10 vales to be divided into 2 rows of 5 each.
This is only a sample data and there are too many vales serialized like this.

I have tried simple for loop but I am not sure how to group those 5 values together.

```
mylist=[]
for id in x:
    for i in id:
        mylist.append(i, id[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slice the list of dicts using [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

```
>>> dics = [x[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(x),5)]
>>> dics
[[{'bsName': 'AC SLEEPER'}, {'bsType': 'ACS'}, {'ischildconcession': 'N'}, {'isseatlayot': 'N'}, {'isseatnmber': 'N'}], [{'bsName': 'AC-JANRATH'}, {'bsType': 'JNR'}, {'ischildconcession': 'N'}, {'isseatlayot': 'Y'}, {'isseatnmber': 'Y'}]]
>>> [{i.keys()[0]:i.values()[0] for i in j} for j in dics]
[{'isseatnmber': 'N', 'bsName': 'AC SLEEPER', 'bsType': 'ACS', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'N'}, {'isseatnmber': 'Y', 'bsName': 'AC-JANRATH', 'bsType': 'JNR', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'Y'}]
```

The step is `5` as you want to split into 5 rows

Comment: correct. But is it possible to group those 5 values in a single dic? In other words a list of 2 dics will make my code easier to maintain.

Comment: Please do tell me the reason to down. I'll certainly make amends

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd define a generator that chunks your list into `n` items at a time:

```
def generate_groups(lst, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i+n]
```

Then simply build up your dictionaries:

```
result = []
for group in generate_groups(x, 5):
    dct = {}
    for item in group:
        dct.update(item)
    result.append(dct)
```

So that:

```
>>> result
[{'bsName': 'AC SLEEPER',
  'bsType': 'ACS',
  'ischildconcession': 'N',
  'isseatlayot': 'N',
  'isseatnmber': 'N'},
 {'bsName': 'AC-JANRATH',
  'bsType': 'JNR',
  'ischildconcession': 'N',
  'isseatlayot': 'Y',
  'isseatnmber': 'Y'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`grouper` recipe** from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) documentation and  [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to group your attributes into key/value tuples that can be used with the [`dict` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
>>> [dict(chain(*[item.items() for item in group])) for group in grouper(x, 5, {})]
[{'isseatnmber': 'N', 'bsName': 'AC SLEEPER', 'bsType': 'ACS', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'N'},
 {'isseatnmber': 'Y', 'bsName': 'AC-JANRATH', 'bsType': 'JNR', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'Y'}]
```

---

#### Explanation

The **`grouper` recipe** from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) documentation allows you to group your key/value dicts together in groups of 5:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>>
>>> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
...     "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
...     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
...     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
...     return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
...
>>> groups = list(grouper(x, 5, {}))
>>> groups
[({'bsName': 'AC SLEEPER'}, {'bsType': 'ACS'}, {'ischildconcession': 'N'}, {'isseatlayot': 'N'}, {'isseatnmber': 'N'}),
 ({'bsName': 'AC-JANRATH'}, {'bsType': 'JNR'}, {'ischildconcession': 'N'}, {'isseatlayot': 'Y'}, {'isseatnmber': 'Y'})]
>>>
```

Then use a **list comprehension and `dict.items()`** to turn the lists of single key/value dicts into key/value tuples:

```
>>> pairs = [[kv.items() for kv in group] for group in groups]
>>> pairs

[[[('bsName', 'AC SLEEPER')], [('bsType', 'ACS')], [('ischildconcession', 'N')], [('isseatlayot', 'N')], [('isseatnmber', 'N')]],
 [[('bsName', 'AC-JANRATH')], [('bsType', 'JNR')], [('ischildconcession', 'N')], [('isseatlayot', 'Y')], [('isseatnmber', 'Y')]]]
```

Now use **[`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)** and [**list unpacking**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to flatten the lists of pairs into lists of key/value tuples that are suitable for the `dict` constructor:

```
>>> itemgroups = [list(chain(*pair)) for pair in pairs]
>>> itemgroups[0]
[('bsName', 'AC SLEEPER'), ('bsType', 'ACS'), ('ischildconcession', 'N'), ('isseatlayot', 'N'), ('isseatnmber', 'N')]
```

And as the last step, use the **[`dict` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)** to turn those pairs of key/value tuples into dictionaries:

```
>>> [dict(items) for items in itemgroups]
[{'isseatnmber': 'N', 'bsName': 'AC SLEEPER', 'bsType': 'ACS', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'N'},
 {'isseatnmber': 'Y', 'bsName': 'AC-JANRATH', 'bsType': 'JNR', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'Y'}]
```

**Note**: All these intermediate `list()` calls were only needed because some of these functions produce generators that will be consumed after iterating once, and otherwise re-using the results for demonstration in the interactive interpreter wouldn't have worked. If you combine all these steps, the intermediate lists aren't needed.

Putting it all together without intermediate lists:

```
>>> [dict(chain(*[item.items() for item in group])) for group in grouper(x, 5, {})]
[{'isseatnmber': 'N', 'bsName': 'AC SLEEPER', 'bsType': 'ACS', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'N'},
 {'isseatnmber': 'Y', 'bsName': 'AC-JANRATH', 'bsType': 'JNR', 'ischildconcession': 'N', 'isseatlayot': 'Y'}]
```